# can we use datagridview as datasource?

Tags: c#, ado.net, datagridview

I'm trying to set the `dataGridView` as a datasource of some other `datagridview`, but it is not working. Please help me.

```
this.dataGridView2.DataSource = this.dataGridView1;
```

No compiler error, but not working as well.

Comment: you can use this this.dataGridView2.DataSource = this.dataGridView1.DataSource

Comment: that i have used but i want that whenever i change in first datagridview, the same is updated in other gridview, and also i don't want to write code in eventhandlers as for that above solution doesnot work and i have to create dataTable.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.dataGridView2.DataSource = this.dataGridView1;
```

this will show no compile error because this.dataGridView2.DataSource is expecting a type of object and you are assigning an object to it, but no datasource assigned here , to do that

```
 this.dataGridView2.DataSource = this.dataGridView1.DataSource
```

assign like this

to Solve the Problem of changing data in datagrid one while changing data on first one

Try this

```
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt.Copy();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nighil sounds close, I don't know if that worked for you but I would not recomend using dataGridView as a datasource, I suggest you should separate out the logic keeping data separate from user controls, also using a 'BindingSource' gives you one easy method for refreshing data;

Say we had a method called 'getTablefromDatasource()' which got the data to be displayed and returned a 'DataTable'

```
DataTable table = getTablefromDatasource();
BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
dataGridView2.DataSource = source;
```

then you can refresh the data with:

```
source.ResetBindings(false);
```